# Which cooking method gives the leanest bacon?

Tags: baking, bacon, low-fat

I've recently discovered the joy that is baking bacon. It's made me curious: does baked bacon render out more fat than pan-fried? How about microwaved?

Answer (score 2):

It believe is more a question of temperature than technique. Low and slow typically renders more fat. When I want a maximum amount of fat rendered out I place thinly sliced bacon in a pan and cover with cold water. I then place over medium-high until the water has evaporated and then some depending on how crispy I want the bacon to be.